# Auto redirect to login page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

I have a trouble with my WP site, I want user to login into other site using soap and save user session_key into cookies. But when I click login button, It redirected to wp-login.php.
I don't want to show default login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to other site login page like this:

```
//add this in functions.php
function redirect_login_page(){

    // Store for checking if this page equals wp-login.php
    $page_viewed = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    // permalink to the custom login page
    $login_page  = "http://other-site.com/login-page-url"

    if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" ) {
        wp_redirect( $login_page );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'init','redirect_login_page' );
```

And Best of luck for setting cookie and then logging in this site with that cookie! :)